# Unable to find a single main class with './mvnw clean verify'

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin, spring-jdbc

[image]I used the command ./mvnw clean verify but got the following error[image]

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.3:repackage (repackage) on project database: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:s
pring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.3:repackage failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.example.database.DatabaseApplication, org.example.database.DatabaseApplication] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```